# Can a semicolon be placed between two sentences if the second sentence begins with a pronoun that refers back to the previous sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, semicolons

Consider the following closely-related sentences:

> Those tribes have been farmers for centuries. They do not desire to do
>   anything else.

would this way of writing the sentences be correct as well:

> Those tribes have been farmers for centuries; they do not desire to do
>   anything else.

Comment: That looks ok. Why not? (Not sarcastic; I’m asking for information.)

Comment: You could place a period (full stop), what's not to use a semi-colon?

Comment: @Kris In your comment you have used an idiom with which I am not familiar. What does "...what's not to use a semi-colon?" mean?

Comment: @WS2 There's no "idiom," *per se*.

Comment: @Kris So what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a semi-colon would be correct in the example sentence!

Comment: -1 Perhaps, but says who? If you have the privilege to post comments, please use "comments" to give your opinion.

Comment: Great question! Semicolons can be used to join 2 related, but independent clauses. That's the reasoning behind my answer :) Thanks for making sure I explain. @Kris

Comment: Please read the FAQ.